# INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a simple auxiliary class to send requests using XmlHttpRequest (code below). But I cant make it work. At google chrome, for example, I get the error `INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11` and at the other browsers I get a status == 0.

```
//@method XRequest: Object constructor. As this implements a singleton, the object can't be created calling the constructor, GetInstance should be called instead
function XRequest() {
    this.XHR = XRequest.CreateXHR();
}
XRequest.instance = null;

//@method static GetInstance: Creates a singleton object of type XRequest. Should be called whenever an object of that type is required.
//@return: an instance of a XRequest object
XRequest.GetInstance = function() {
    if(XRequest.instance == null) {
        XRequest.instance = new XRequest();
    }
    return XRequest.instance;
}

//@method static CreateXHR: Implments a basic factory method for creating a XMLHttpRequest object
//@return: XMLHttp object or null
XRequest.CreateXHR = function() {
    var xhr = null;
    var factory = [
        function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < factory.length; ++i) {
        var f = factory[i];
        xhr = f();
        if(xhr) return xhr;
    }
    return null;
}

XRequest.prototype.SetRequestHeader = function(name, value) {
    if(this.XHR) {
        this.XHR.setRequestHeader(name, value);
    }
}

XRequest.prototype.SendRequest = function(args) {
    var async = true;
    var type = "";
    var url = "";
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    var body = null;
    var success = null; 
    var failure = null;

    for(e in args) {
        switch(e) {
            case "async":
                async = args[e];
                break;
            case "type":
                type = args[e];
                break;
            case "success":
                success = args[e];
                break;
            case "failure":
                failure = args[e];
                break;
            case "url":
                url = args[e];
                break;
            case "username":
                username = args[e];
                break;
            case "password":
                password = args[e];
                break;
            case "body":
                body = args[e];
            break;
            case "setHeader":
                var h = args[e].split(":");
                if(h.length == 2) {
                    this.SetRequestHeader(h[0], h[1]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    var that = this;
    this.XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        alert("readyState == " + that.XHR.readyState + "  status == " + that.XHR.status);
        if(that.XHR.readyState == 4) {
            if(that.XHR.status == 200 || that.XHR.status == 0) {
                if(success) success(that.XHR);
            } else {
                if(failure) failure();
            }
        }
    };
    this.XHR.open(type, url, async, username, password);
    this.XHR.send(body);
}
```

**Example of usage:**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        var x = XRequest.GetInstance();
        x.SendRequest({type:"GET",
            setHeader:"Accept:text/html, image/png, image/*, */*",
            url: "http://your_server.com/getData?param1=test",
            success:onSuccess, failure:onFail
        });
    }

    function onSuccess(obj) {
        alert("OK");                
    }

    function onFail() {
        alert("Not at this time!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd bother to write something like this, except maybe for fun. This doesn't answer your question but I advise you to make that "for" loop be: "for (var e in args) ..."

Comment: It's not for fun. This will run in an embedded browser and the code uses http requests a lot, that's why I put it inside a class to simplify its usage. Also, the code is not complete yet!

Comment: Well why wouldn't you just use one of the many, many open source frameworks that already provide such functionality? They've already got the bugs worked out and the cross-browser problems solved.

Comment: Because then don't work very well in the proprietary browser we use

Comment: @Pointy I'd advise against the `for..in` since they are better suited for objects and not arrays

Comment: @Justin agreed, but I'd double-advise against doing it with a global variable :-)

Comment: @Pointy There is no global in the OP's original statement: `for(var i = 0; i < factory.length; ++i)`

Comment: @Justin Look in the "SendRequest" function

Comment: @Pointy Ah yes, I see it now.  You are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless, you can simplify your `SendRequest` method by creating a mixin instead of using a giant `switch`.

```
XRequest.prototype.SendRequest = function(params) {
    var defaultParams = {
        async:    true,
        type:     "",
        url:      "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
        body:     null,
        success:  null,
        failure:  null
    };

    for ( var i in defaultParams ) {
        if ( defaultParams.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof params[i] == "undefined" ) {
            params[i] = defaultParams[i];
        }
    }

    var that = this;
    this.XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( that.XHR.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( that.XHR.status == 200 || that.XHR.status == 0 ) {
                if ( params.success ) {
                    params.success(that.XHR);
                }
            } else {
                if ( params.failure ) {
                    params.failure();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    this.XHR.open(
        params.type, parms.url, params.async, params.username, params.password
    );

    // It doesn't make sense to have a for/switch here when you're only handling
    // one case
    if ( params.setHeader ) {
        var h = params.setHeader.split(":");
        if ( h.length == 2) {
            this.SetRequestHeader(h[0], h[1]);
        }
    }

    this.XHR.send(params.body);
};
```

Also be careful: your existing `for..in` loops have two distinct problems:

1. You're not using `var` and causing a global to be created: `for (e in args)` should be `for (var e in args)`
2. Whenever you use `for..in`, you should always check to make sure that each key is a direct member of the object, and not something inherited inadvertently through prototype

.

```
for ( var i in obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40):

Problem in this ajax library.

`XHR.setRequestHeader()` must be called after `XHR.open()`.

```
// @method XRequest: Object constructor. As this implements a singleton, the object can't be created calling the constructor, GetInstance should be called instead
function XRequest()
{
    this.XHR = XRequest.CreateXHR();
}

XRequest.instance = null;


// @method static GetInstance: Creates a singleton object of type XRequest. Should be called whenever an object of that type is required.
// @return: an instance of a XRequest object
XRequest.GetInstance = function()
{
    if(XRequest.instance == null)
    {
        XRequest.instance = new XRequest();
    }

    return XRequest.instance;
}

// @method static CreateXHR: Implments a basic factory method for creating a XMLHttpRequest object
// @return: XMLHttp object or null
XRequest.CreateXHR = function()
{
    var xhr = null;
    var factory = [
                    function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
                    function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); },
                    function() { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
                ];

    for(var i = 0; i < factory.length; ++i)
    {
        var f = factory[i];
        xhr = f();
        if(xhr)
            return xhr;
    }

    return null;
}

XRequest.prototype.SetRequestHeader = function(name, value)
{
    if(this.XHR)
    {
        //alert(name+'|||'+value);
        this.XHR.setRequestHeader(name, value);
    }
}

XRequest.prototype.SendRequest = function(args)
{
    var async = true;
    var type = "";
    var url = "";
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    var body = null;
    var success = null; 
    var failure = null;

    for(e in args)
    {
        switch(e)
        {
            case "async":
                async = args[e];
                break;

            case "type":
                type = args[e];
                break;

            case "success":
                success = args[e];
                break;
            case "failure":
                failure = args[e];
                break;

            case "url":
                url = args[e];
                break;

            case "username":
                username = args[e];
                break;

            case "password":
                password = args[e];
                break;

            case "body":
                body = args[e];
                break;
        }
    }

    var that = this;
    this.XHR.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            alert("readyState == " + that.XHR.readyState + "  status == " + that.XHR.status);
            if(that.XHR.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(that.XHR.status == 200 || that.XHR.status == 0)
                {
                    if(success)
                        success(that.XHR);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(failure)
                        failure();
                }
            }
        };

    this.XHR.open(type, url, async, username, password);
    for(e in args)
    {
        switch(e)
        {
            case "setHeader":
                var h = args[e].split(":");             
                if(h.length == 2)
                {
                    this.SetRequestHeader(h[0], h[1]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    this.XHR.send(body);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it before asking here, based on that post http://lists.apple.com/archives/dashboard-dev/2006/Dec/msg00007.html, and didn't work.

Comment: "Problem in this ajax library. XHR.setRequestHeader() must be called after XHR.open()" -> thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 6):

Usually this error occurs with the XMLHttpRequest when you call the open method with async = true, or you leave the async parameter undefined so it defaults to asynchronous, and then you access the status or responseText properties. Those properties are only available after you do a synchronous call, or on the readyState becoming ready (once the asynchronous call responds). I suggest you first try with async = false, and then switch to it being true and use the onReadyStateChange.

Comment: exactly what I needed: I checked for status, but not for readyState. But it's important to have readyState == 4 before checking anything else

Comment: Pointed out something critical and not so obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error occurred when i tried to access `xhr.statusText` within the `xhr.onreadystatechange` method, however retrieving `xhr.readyState` went just fine.